# EF4.1 Code First: Stored Procedure with output parameter

Tags: entity-framework, stored-procedures, parameters, ef-code-first

I use Entity Framework 4.1 Code First. I want to call a stored procedure that has an output parameter and retrieve the value of that output parameter in addition to the strongly typed result set. Its a search function with a signature like this

```
public IEnumerable<MyType> Search(int maxRows, out int totalRows, string searchTerm) { ... }
```

I found lots of hints to "Function Imports" but that is not compatible with Code First.
I can call stored procedures using Database.SqlQuery(...) but that does not work with output parameters.

Can I solve that problem using EF4.1 Code First at all?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`SqlQuery` works with output parameters but you must correctly define SQL query and setup `SqlParameter`s. Try something like:

```
var outParam = new SqlParameter();
outParam.ParameterName = "TotalRows";
outParam.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int;
outParam.ParameterDirection = ParameterDirection.Output;

var data = dbContext.Database.SqlQuery<MyType>("sp_search @SearchTerm, @MaxRows, @TotalRows OUT", 
               new SqlParameter("SearchTerm", searchTerm), 
               new SqlParameter("MaxRows", maxRows),
               outParam);
var result = data.ToList();
totalRows = (int)outParam.Value;
```

Comment: Perfect! The missing pieces were "ParameterDirection.Output" and the "OUT" after "@totalRows" in the query parameter list. Thanks!

Comment: This doesn't seem to work when you have multiple OUTPUT parameters.  The value for each is null.  Any luck doing this with multiple OUTPUT parameters?

Comment: my sp returns nothing.... so what should be done in that case....SqlQuery<null> is not working....any suggesions?

Comment: @AnilPurswani: In such case you need to use `ExecuteSqlCommand` instead of `SqlQuery`