# SqlParameter returns null in Entity Framework SqlQuery

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first, sqlparameter

I am materializing entities through a stored procedure in Entity Framework Code-First.  The Stored Procedure takes an int parameter and outputs both a selection of records and several output parameters.  For whatever reason, I am getting Null back on my output parameters while executing the Proc from SQL Management studio results in expected behavior; all output parameters have values.  My entities are being materialized, so at least that is working...

## EF Code

```
        SqlParameter DocsWithHits = new SqlParameter()
        {
            ParameterName = "DocumentsWithHits",
            Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output,
            Value = null,
            SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.Int
        };

        SqlParameter TotalGB = new SqlParameter()
        {
            ParameterName = "TotalGb",
            Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output,
            Value = null,
            SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.Float
        };

        ObservableCollection<SearchResult> ResultCollection;
        ResultCollection = new ObservableCollection<SearchResult>(db.Database.SqlQuery<SearchResult>(
            "exec ListSearchResultsWithTotals @SearchAnalysisID, @DocumentsWithHits, @RelatedDocuments, @TotalDocuments, @TotalGb, @DocumentsWithHitsNotExported, @RelatedDocumentsNotExported, @TotalDocumentsNotExported, @TotalGbNotExported",
            new SqlParameter
            {
                ParameterName = "SearchAnalysisID",
                Value = this.SearchAnalysisId
            },
            DocsWithHits,
            TotalGB));
```

## SQL Profiler

The SQL that is generated from the SqlQuery method is below.  I captured it in Profiler.  When executed I get records and null output parameters.

```
declare @p4 int
set @p4=NULL
declare @p5 float
exec sp_executesql N'exec ListSearchResultsWithTotals @SearchAnalysisID, @DocumentsWithHits, @TotalGb',N'@SearchAnalysisID int,@DocumentsWithHits int output,@TotalGb float output',@SearchAnalysisID=170,@DocumentsWithHits=@p4 output,@TotalGb=@p5 output
select @p4, @p5, @p6, @p7, @p8, @p9, @p10, @p11
```

Am I using SqlParameter wrong or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use `OUT` keyword in SQL passed to `SqlQuery` (example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8180310/ef4-1-code-first-stored-procedure-with-output-parameter)). Also make sure that you are reading those parameters after you iterated or closed the main result set of the query (it should be done by `ObservableCollection` constructor).