# How to retrieve output parameter from stored procedure by EF code first

Tags: c#, entity-framework, stored-procedures

i am new in EF and working with EF code first. just got a link https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/How-to-retrieve-output-e85526ba which show how to use read output type param by EF db first. so anyone tell me how to retrieve output parameter from stored procedure by EF code first ?

if possible give me small sample code or redirect me to relevant articles.

thanks

### I got a solution

```
var outParam = new SqlParameter();
outParam.ParameterName = "TotalRows";
outParam.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int;
outParam.ParameterDirection = ParameterDirection.Output;

var data = dbContext.Database.SqlQuery<MyType>("sp_search @SearchTerm, @MaxRows, @TotalRows OUT", 
               new SqlParameter("SearchTerm", searchTerm), 
               new SqlParameter("MaxRows", maxRows),
               outParam);
var result = data.ToList();
totalRows = (int)outParam.Value;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [EF4.1 Code First: Stored Procedure with output parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8180310/ef4-1-code-first-stored-procedure-with-output-parameter)

Comment: @ChrisBint thanks a lot for your link.

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/alexj/2009/11/07/tip-41-how-to-execute-t-sql-directly-against-the-database/

Comment: I never suspected that "OUT" could save my day. Upvoted!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To retrieve the data for a stored procedure call, you can use the following

```
using(var db = new YourConext())
{
       var details = db.Database.SqlQuery<YourType>("exec YourProc @p", 
                      new SqlParameter("@p", YourValue));
}
```

**YourType**: might be  int or string or long or even  a ComplexType

**@p**: in case if the stored procedure has parameters and you can define as many as you need from parameters

if you need more information about SqlQuery , you might check the following

1. [Writing SQL queries for entities](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592907.aspx)
2. [Entity Framework Code First and Stored Procedures](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/299/entity-framework-code-first-and-stored-procedures)

Hope this will help you

Comment: This doesn't show how to retreive the resulting value in the output parameter.

Comment: This is not answer the question

Answer (score -1):

This way we can also call a stored procedure without using `exec` command.

```
using (var context = new BloggingContext()) 
{ 
    var blogs = context.Blogs.SqlQuery("dbo.GetBlogs").ToList(); 
}
```

You can also pass parameters to a stored procedure using the following syntax:

```
using (var context = new BloggingContext()) 
{ 
    var blogId = 1; 

    var blogs = context.Blogs.SqlQuery("dbo.GetBlogById @p0", blogId).Single(); 
}
```

Comment: The question is about output parameters. This doesn't answer the question, it just talks about how to pass parameters in general.